# Can we configure SSL certificate for Customer Communities

Tags: force.com-sites, ssl, custom-domain

We have a customer community in Salesforce, where user can login with their username/password.

We would like to map our custom domain and secure SSL certificate on the site.
I found few article which explains that custom domain is possible for communities.

But, there is no way to provide custom SSL certificate and we need to use "secure.force.com" domain for SSL.

Has anyone faced similar issues? Because, I think most of websites needs their own domain to be captured for SEO purpose. Also, if we need to create a secure e-Commerce site, it will show force.com certificate instead of branded certificate.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Salesforce supports https](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/communities_custom_domain_URL.htm) for communities since Summer 14. As mentioned in the doc, you will first need to contact Salesforce to enable for your org and take it from there. [Here](https://blog.internetcreations.com/2014/09/moving-salesforce-communities-to-custom-domains-with-https/) [are](http://thinkaholics.com/salesforce/how-to-add-a-custom-url-to-salesforce-communities/) some blogs related to this.