# Promote site visualforce page on google results

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, seo

I have created a VF landing page on SF site and I wish to promote it on google results (Organic) I've added tags as below yet still it doesn't do the work 
any ideas how can I promote the page?

```
<head>
    <title>promote text</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="promote text" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="promote text, promote text2" />....
```

Comment: Going to leave this open on the chance that there is something specific to sites that causes SEO to not work. Otherwise this could be off topic here

Comment: Couple of interesting posts around this: 1 - Must have custom domain: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67366/can-we-configure-ssl-certificate-for-customer-communities - and 2 - Issues with dulpicate pages in SEO - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99051/salesforce-visualforce-website-has-lots-of-duplicate-content-pages - Not many answers around this though so not sure there is anything specific to Sites or salesforce